# how to call a nested jquery function from html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a `addtext()` function from `html onclick()` that is nested inside `add()` function. I want to call the second function. How can i approach this?

Here i have a link with `add()` function that shows a textbox and an  `ADD` button with `addtext()`. 
The `add()` function checks for text and if text is present, it generates a new text box. 
Now i want the add button to take that text and from the textbox and set it in replacement of the textbox.
clicking the `ADD` button will take it to `addtext()` which is inside the `add()` function.

Html code:

```
     <a id = "newcard" href="#" onclick="add()" >
            <b style ="color: #444444">Add Card...</b>
     </a>

     <div>
          <span id = "show-ta"><textarea id="txtarea" style =" 
      display:none"></textarea><span>
          <span id = "newbutton"><button id = "firstbutton" class ="btn btn-
      success nbutton"onclick="addtext()" style ="display:none">Add</button>
          </span>
     </div>
```

Jquery code:

```
     function add(){
      var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('textarea'));
      if ( $('#txtarea').css('display') == 'none' ){
    $('#txtarea').css('display', 'block');
       }
      if ( $('#firstbutton').css('display') == 'none' ){
    $('#firstbutton').css('display', 'block');
       }
      var wrapper = $('#show-ta');
      var button = $(document.createElement('button'));

    if(wrapper.find('textarea').last().val().length) {
       var x =wrapper.find('textarea').last().val();
        function addtext()
        {

        }
        wrapper.append('<textarea class="t-one"></textarea>');
        wrapper.append('<button class ="btn btn-success 
   nbutton">Add</button>').appendTo('#cardarea').insertAfter('#cardtitle');;
        //button.addClass("btn btn-success");
        wrapper.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter('#cardtitle');
        wrapper.addClass('t-one');
       // var text =$('textarea:nth-last-child(2)').val().length;

        //wrapper.addClass('nbutton');
    }
```

Comment: please give us more details.

Comment: I want to call the second function? means

Comment: Can you give a code example ?

Comment: Please add your sample code in your question and give some proper description.

Comment: Why do you need to encapsulate `addtext()`? Surely you can just move `addtext()` outside of the add function?    `function add() { .... }   function addtext() { .... }`

Comment: because `addtext()` will read the value of the previous `textarea`. And the `textareas` are generated at `add()`

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the nested function to a property like this `addText.add = add;` then you can call that function in `onClick` event.

```js
function addText()
    {
        // irrelevant code here
        function add(arg){
            console.log( arg );
        }
    
        addText.add = add;
    }
    addText();
```

```html
<button onclick="addText.add('Nested function')">Click me</button>
```

**EDIT:**

Updated the snippet as per your code

```js
function add() {
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('textarea'));
  if ($('#txtarea').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#txtarea').css('display', 'block');
  }
  if ($('#firstbutton').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#firstbutton').css('display', 'block');
  }
  var wrapper = $('#show-ta');
  var button = $(document.createElement('button'));

  if (wrapper.find('textarea').last().val().length) {
    var x = wrapper.find('textarea').last().val();

    function addtext() {
      alert('working');
    }
    add.addtext = addtext;
    wrapper.append('<textarea class="t-one"></textarea>');
    wrapper.append('<button class="btn btn-success nbutton ">Add</button>').appendTo('#cardarea').insertAfter('#cardtitle');;

    wrapper.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter('#cardtitle');
    wrapper.addClass('t-one');

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="newcard" href="#" onclick="add()">
  <b style="color: #444444">Add Card...</b>
</a>
<div>
  <span id="show-ta">
  <textarea id="txtarea" style ="display:none">
  </textarea>
  </span>
  <span id="newbutton">
  <button id = "firstbutton" class ="btn btn-success nbutton" onclick="add.addtext()" style="display:none">Add
  </button>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i did the same and i get `add.addtext is not a function` error :(

Comment: did you call the function `add` before the click happens? then only this assign will happen `addText.add = add;`

Comment: @Chri.s You need the change the `Load type` to `No wrap in head` in JsFiddle.

Comment: @Chri.s I'm waiting for her response to my previous comment.

Comment: @sanjana Can you check it now?

Comment: @sanjana You have to check the button below the text area.

Comment: The problem was calling `add.addtext()` before `add()` inside html

Comment: @sanjana Actually you are doing that when you click `Add card...` link did you check my updated answer

Comment: yes  i saw ur answer but my problem is i cannot call `add()` before `addtext()` because popover is calling tht `add()` and the popover is inside the div element that contains the button with `addtext()`